# Javascript Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: selectMove is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting this error in the below code on the last script line in my handlebars file "Javascript Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: selectMove is not defined""

```
       <html>
<head>
    <title>Pokemon Database</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/boostrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
    <script src="/static/selectMove.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/updatepokemon.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Update sadfasdf: </h1>
<form id="update-pokemon" action="/pokemon" method="post">
    Pokemon Name: <input type="text" name="pokemonname" value="sadfasdf"><br>
    Evolution Level: <input type="text" name="evolutionlevel" value="0"><br>
    Primary Move: <select name="movename" id="move-selector">
        <option value="1">Vine Whip</option>
        <option value="2">Razor Leaf</option>
        <option value="3">Solar Beam</option>
        <option value="4">Ember</option>
        <option value="5">Flame Burst</option>
        <option value="6">Flamethrower</option>
        <option value="7">Bubble</option>
        <option value="8">Water Gun</option>
        <option value="9">Hydro Pump</option>
        <option value="10">String Shot</option>
        </select><br>
        </form>
    <button onclick="updatePokemon(13)">Update</button>
    <script>selectMove(1);</script> 
</body>
```

I think it may relate to the selectMove.js file that contains the selectMove function, which is below here

```
function selectMove(id) {
        $("#move-selector").val(pokemonid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The defer attribute is only for external scripts (should only be used
>   if the src attribute is present).

Comment: That makes sense - however I removed the defer attribute and it's still giving me this error.

Comment: make sure that you have loaded selectMove.js file before you call that function

Comment: Do you mean the script tag?  See above for the edited full HTML